# Access database from background service

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-context, sqliteopenhelper

I want to access the data from SQLiteDatabse in SERVICE. I created the object db and tried to access the database from service, but its not working. To access the database content in `onStart` method of the service what should I do. I searched a lot, but creating context by `getApplicationContext()` method didn't work for me. Please help me with code to access database in SERVICE.

Comment: functions like db.isOpen() etc. are working fine. But, when i fire a select query using db.rawQuery() it don't work. Plz help me to retrieve values in the service.

Comment: Thank you friends. I succeeded to solve this problem. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Now I got another problem. I tried firing update query using rawQuery() as well as db.update() & content values but, still it is not working. Is there any other way to update table in the SERVICE? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Android `Service` doesn't have such method `onStart()`. You can use either `onStartCommand()` or `onCreate()`.

Comment: Sorry,it was a mistake. But can u tell me how to retrieve values/update values of database from service.

Comment: SQLiteDatabase db = (new Storage(getBaseContext()).getReadableDatabase();                       
   db = (new Storage(getBaseContext()).getWritableDatabase();

Comment: storage is my database class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper. I am creating object db as shown above & using it as db.rawQuery(qry);

Comment: In short, I am trying to access database in SEVICE same like we do in ACTIVITY.

Comment: Yes, i tried even getApplicationContext() too. But, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to options, what you can do.

**The Frist Option is following:**

---

You allways use a static context (for example the mainactivity), over which you allways acces the DB. You can do it like that:

```
public static Activity thi;
```

**The Secound Option is following:**

---

In your Service you can call:

```
this.getApplicationContext();
```

With this Context you can also write into your db.

Best Regards

safari

Comment: I tried like this:   db = (new Storage(this.getApplicationContext()).getReadableDatabase();           And same for getWritableDatabase()  but after firing select query using rawquery() doesnt retrieve data.

Comment: And can you please tell me more about static context u have written above. I dont uderstand it. Should I use this static context in SERVICE?

Comment: you can use it, but you don't have to like this you do following. first you instantiate it. thi.getApplicationContext(); and it should work fine. ;)

Comment: I tried like this:  private static Activity m;                                           db=(new Storage(m.getApplicationContext())).getReadableDatabase();
                                                       db=(new Storage(m.getApplicationContext())).getWritableDatabase();            db.rawQuery(qry,null);       It didn't work. Is this right?

Comment: Can anyone please tell me what mistake i am doing in the above code?